# Array of Pins, Color not changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, annotations, mapkit

I am trying to dynamically set the pin color for these two points which belong to different classes however they do not show a different color on my map. Do you see any issue in my for loop for my array, towards the bottom?

```
#define UNIVERSITY_LATITUDE 35.22836;
#define UNIVERSITY_LONGITUDE 126.84784;
#define HOTEL_LATITUDE 34.55;
#define HOTEL_LONGITUDE 127.36;


@implementation MapKitViewController


//Synthesize the getters and setters of the map view
@synthesize mapView;



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray *annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;

   //used to test Annotations of map, will be replaced by for loop to insert new points
    PhotoPoint *photoAnn;
    photoAnn = [[PhotoPoint alloc] init];
    location.latitude =UNIVERSITY_LATITUDE;
    location.longitude = UNIVERSITY_LONGITUDE;
    photoAnn.coordinate = location;
    [photoAnn setTitle:@"GIST"];
    [photoAnn setSubtitle:@"University"];
    [photoAnn setAnnotationType:@"Photo"];
    [annotations addObject:photoAnn];

    CommercialPoint *commAnn;
    commAnn = [[CommercialPoint alloc] init];
    location.latitude =HOTEL_LATITUDE;
    location.longitude = HOTEL_LONGITUDE;
    commAnn.coordinate = location;
    [commAnn setTitle:@"Hotel"];
    [commAnn setSubtitle:@"Hotel Center"];
    [commAnn setAnnotationType:@"Commercial"];
    [annotations addObject:commAnn];

    for (id eachObject in annotations){
        if ([eachObject isKindOfClass:[PhotoPoint class]])
        {
            photoAnn.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
        }
        if ([eachObject isKindOfClass:[CommercialPoint class]])
        {
            commAnn.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
        }

    //send the delgate messages to the mapview
    mapView.delegate = self;
    [self.mapView addAnnotations:annotations];
```

Comment: where is your for loop going to end?

Comment: for (id eachObject in annotations), doesnt that imply that the for loop ends when it goes through all the objects in the array?

Comment: @user3036511: In the code posted, it does not show the closing `}` of the `for` loop.  So it's not clear what code is in the loop.  Regardless, the pinColor ultimately needs to be set in the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method.  If you have implemented that method, please edit your question and add that code.